# Facebook permission dialogue allows users to change their email

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I prompted for the "email" permission in my Facebook application. However, the permission dialogue allows users to change their email address. I have seen some websites like [ww.imdb.com](http://ww.imdb.com) that prompts for email permission, but don't allow users to change the email address.

I want to do the same. How to do this?

Comment: @zerkms, the do require "email" in scope along with some other permissions as well. `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=127059960673829&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.imdb.com%2Foauth%2Flogin&scope=email%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_birthday`

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: yep, but they just request permissions with another dialog `permissions.request`

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: where am I wrong? I currently see that I was talking about

Comment: @zerkms, there is no such thing as `permissions.request` dialog, it's "OAuth Dialog". IMDB implementing authorization using ["Authorization Request"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.1) as OAuth 2.0 spec, Facebook is doing redirect to URL containing `permissions.request` (changing and adding some parameters to interrupt regular OAuth flow with "OAuth Dialog", that's it Facebook have modified OAuth 2.0 implementation)

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: there is **no difference** between Authorization Request and implementing  it in some manual way you're talking about (though there is no any manual way - because everything you do passed through FB APIs, which are common)

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: here is **general** facebook sample code: http://fa-cebook.zerkms.ru/examples/example.php --- without any special things. And you see - you **cannot** change email. " that's it Facebook have modified OAuth 2.0 implementation" --- no, they didn't. Facebook follow common oauth v2 flow. And oauth v2 doesn't forbid to use some custom endpoints to use within the flow

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: what are you talking about?! I didn't remove anything related to subject!! Do you have anything to say on-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. Just go to application settings -> Advanced Settings. 
In Migrations section enable the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" option and Save.

Now, you will see the new version of permission dialogue box that does not allow users to change the email address.

Answer (score 1):

[IMDB](http://imdb.com) implemented Facebook authorization via usage of [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22) (see [Authorization Request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.1) in OAuth 2.0 specs for details)

If you using any of the flows listed in Facebook documentation for [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) you'll not be allowed deny possibility of changing email.

In fact I'm think this is an issue that Facebook does not allow changing of email in the plain OAuth 2.0 flow (and will file a bug about that!).

Comment: There is no plain and "non-plain" authentication for now, since now everything is driven via oAuth v2.0

Comment: Facebook just providing simplified version of OAuth 2.0 authentication flow with [Oauth Dalog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) which you doesn't require to use and may do auth just as in OAuth 2.0 spec (this is what I called plain and think it's acceptable, if you not OK with the word "plain" as I use it and think it's confusing someone, than go on and edit my answer.)

Comment: @zerkms, what you say here is just wrong! OAuth 2.0 isn't part of Facebook API in any way. And citing Facebook documentation "We support a number of different OAuth flows". If you think my answer is incorect - Downvote, if you thing you may improve it do it.

Comment: oauth v2.0 is the protocol the FB API authentication and **authorization** is based on